# Suppose $N$ is a normal subgroup of finite group $G$ with prime index

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $N$ is a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ with prime index $p$. And conjugacy classes of $x \in G$, $ccl(x)$ is a subset of $N$.

Show that either conjugacy class of $x$ in $G$ coincides with its conjugacy class in $N$ or is a disjoint union of $p$ conjugacy classes in $N$ of equal size.

---

I have noticed that a normal subgroup is a union of ccls so $\bigcup_{g\in N}ccl(x)=N$, then how can I show they concide? I know I probably need to apply orbit-stabilizer somewhere to get that 1 or p.

Comment: By the Second Isomorphism Theorem, $C_G(x)/C_N(x)$ is isomorphic to a subgroups of $G/N$ so it has order $1$ or $p$, and so you get the corresponding two cases for the conjugacy class of $x$ in $N$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you explain a bit more please? We haven't covered second iso thm and inner group product yet.

Comment: The 2nd Isomorphism Thm says that if $N \unlhd G$ and $H \le G$ then $HN/N \cong H/H \cap N$. To prove it define $\phi:H \to HN/N$ by $\phi(h) = hN$, show $\ker \phi = H \cap N$ and use the 1st Isomorphism Thm. Apply it to this problem with $H = C_G(x)$ to give $C_G(x)/C_N(x) \cong NC_G(x)/N \le G/N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Derek's hint: we can define an action $\;G\times G\to G,\,\,g\cdot x:=x^g:=g^{-1}xg\;$ . Then we know we have

$$\left|\mathcal O_G(x)\right|=\left\{x^g\;|\;g\in G\}\right|=[G:G_x]\,,\,\text{with}\;G_x:=\{g\in G\;|\;x^g=x\}=:C_G(x)$$

Take now $\;x\in N\;$ . Since $\;N\lhd G\;$ , we know $\;\mathcal O_G(x)\subset N\;$ , and taking the restriction of the conjugation action to $\;N\;$ , we get

$$|\mathcal O_N(x)|=[N:N_x]\;,\;\;N_x:=\{n\in N\;|\;x^n=x\}= C_N(x)=N\cap C_G(x)$$

Clearly, $\;C_N(x)\lhd C_G(x)\;$ , and we get from the second isomorphism theorem

$$C_G(x)/C_N(x)=C_G(x)/(N\cap C_G(x))\cong NC_G(x)/N\le G/N$$

and from Lagrange's theorem we get that $\;[C_G(x):C_N(x)]\in\{1,\,p\}\;$ , as required.